# Wireless Link works, but can't connect laptop to internet

Tags: dell-latitude

I have recently switched over from BT to O2 for broadband. After setting everything up, my laptop and smart phone can access the internet via Network cables and Wireless, also my Roku music server can stream music.

The big mystery is an old Dell laptop Latitude PP04S, Intel Pentium M Processor 1200 MHz running Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 (which used to connect to the old BT router). It can see and connect to the WiFi signal, but can't access the internet.

Does anyone know what's going on or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Do you get a local IP? have you tried to ping anything (local/remote)? Did this laptop previously have static IP? Are there any errors you see when you connect? Please provide more details about the router and any errors you see.

Comment: Hi kyle,Thanks for answering my post, how do i know if i get a local IP? not sure if it was a static Ip, i am currently accessing the internet on my other Dell Laptop, how can I check its settings?

Comment: On the laptop that is having issues go to start>run type in "cmd" (no quotes) then type in "ipconifg" also no quotes. Post the IP address here it should look like: 169.65.45.122 or something similar.

Comment: To add to the above maybe a DNS issue as I recall an old BT service where I had to manually set the DNS.  On the cmd prompt try "ping 67.215.65.132"

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the laptop previously required a static IP address or manual configuration, and now your network details have changed. Try setting the **Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) Properties** to `Obtain an IP address automatically` and `Obtain DNS server address automatically`.

[image: TCP/IP]

To get to these settings, go to:

- **Control Panel > Network Connections**
- **Right-click** on the wireless adapter and **click** `Properties`
- **Double-click** on `Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)`

Comment: Thanks to everyone, i will check these options out and get back to you all may be a couple of hours.